# How to declare/reuse a type inside of an interface

Tags: typescript

I am trying to find a way to declare a type inside of an interface to avoid repeating myself

for example:

```
interface PopulateOptionsTs<Path extends keyof PopulateProps<DocType>, Select, DocType> {
  path: Path
  select?: Select
  populate: DocType[Path]
}
```

as you see in the code - Path is a generic value, which I can safely remove and replace with "keyof PopulateProps.." instead, but I have it in two places, I might even add a few more properties in future that will try to use that Path type.

Is there a way to avoid copy pasting in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using a generic parameter *purely* as type alias.

First reason is that all generic parameters are required to be present when using a generic type. That makes awkward if you trying to use this type, since you have to provide a type that could be easily derived.

The second reason is that it's more complicated and difficult to maintain. You may get typescript errors that are hard to understand and debug.

If you want an alias to use here, you should declare a new type alongside `PopulateOptionsTs`. Something like:

```
type PopulatePaths<T> = keyof PopulateProps<T>

interface PopulateOptionsTs<Select, DocType> {
  path: PopulatePaths<DocType>
  select?: Select
  populate: DocType[PopulatePaths<DocType>]
}
```

Although it's not that much simpler, it does allow you to "name" the type you reuse.

---

All that said, it does kind of look like `Path` should be a generic parameter here because the type of the `path` argument can be referenced in the type of the `populate` argument to refine that type to be something more specific.

And if so, what you have already seems optimal to me.